VS visual studio Jupyter Notebook does not use the correct path
I work on a Windows PC and a laptop. When I start the vs code on the laptop I get the following error: The terminal process failed to launch: Invalid starting directory "\DESKTOPMEDION\Documenten\Programmeren\Python\Editors", review your terminal.integrated.cwd setting. The directory path is referring to the path on the PC.
On the laptop I have checked the settings.json file and even fully removed it to reset it but the error remains. Also I have all extensions disabled and restarted the vs code. Also the settings.json file on the PC removed, still the error occurs. How can I resolve this error.

After spending a whole afternoon trying to reinstall Visual Studio Code several times, deleting the settings.json file, etc., I removed Visual Studio Code again but also searched for all remaining files, cache files, etc., which are not removed from my system upon uninstallation. I was pretty annoyed because after a new installation, all settings were reinstalled, along with the errors, due to the residual files. The tentacles of Microsoft Visual Studio Code reach deep into your system, so be aware of this!! Problem solved for now.

So any ideas how the visual studio installed on a laptop is using a starting directory from a completely different computer? I have no idea what you did but it sounds like you didn't install properly at all. This answer provides no real insight into the problem, what caused it, and how it was fixed. Also btw many applications leave behind settings files ... this is usually a good thing since upgrades, re-installs, repairs can maintain the settings - nothing nefarious about VSCode on this score (it is nice when an application has a "completely remove" option but that is less common).

Also not at all clear why you think your settings.json was a problem to begin with. I seriously doubt any cache files were causing this problem either.
